# Return AVG in $group stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i try to move foward and i think i'm not so far anymore.thaks again for your help.I get only one date result with the request (see edit).I don't know how i can get the result by day.I have adjusted the match condition including all the required document.I don't know why you put $first.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ "$match": {"CollectionTime": { $gte: ISODate("2016-11-   10T00:00:00.000Z")},"Rx Rate": { $exists: true }}},
{ "$group": {
"_id": "$ResourceName",
DeviceName: { $first: "$DeviceName" },
ResourceName: { $first: "$ResourceName" },
Date: { $first: "$CollectionTime" },
AVGRxRATE: { $avg: "$Rx Rate" },
AVGTxRATE: { $avg: "$Tx Rate" },
MaxRxRATE: { $max: "$Rx Rate" },
MaxTxRATE: { $max: "$Tx Rate" }
}
},
{ 
$project: { 
_id: 0,
DeviceName: 1, 
ResourceName: 1, 
Date: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$Date" } },
AVGRxRATE: 1,
AVGTxRATE: 1,
MaxRxRATE: 1,
        MaxTxRATE: 1
    } 
  }
  ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for - you have a few unnecessary steps in your aggregation pipeline.

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is for splitting an array into separate documents, and [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) is for reshaping or renaming fields.

```
db.u2000.aggregate([
    { "$match": {"CollectionTime": { $gte: ISODate("2016-11-05T00:00:00.000Z")}}},
    { "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            AVGRxRATE: { $avg: "$Rx Rate" },
            AVGTxRATE: { $avg: "$Tx Rate" },
            MaxRxRATE: { $max: "$Rx Rate" },
            MaxTxRATE: { $max: "$Tx Rate" }
        }
    }
])
```

This results in the following for your 'one' document case but should work for multiple documents:

```
{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "AVGRxRATE" : 522, 
    "AVGTxRATE" : 176, 
    "MaxRxRATE" : NumberLong(522), 
    "MaxTxRATE" : NumberLong(176) 
}
```

*** EDIT ***

Run the following aggregate to get the exact output you want... note that this is not really grouping on anything in particular and is more of a manipulation of one document to shape it the way you're asking since we are grouping by null.

```
db.u2000.aggregate([
    { "$match": {"CollectionTime": { $gte: ISODate("2016-11-05T00:00:00.000Z")}}},
    { "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            DeviceName: { $first: "$DeviceName" },
            ResourceName: { $first: "$ResourceName" },
            Date: { $first: "$CollectionTime" },
            AVGRxRATE: { $avg: "$Rx Rate" },
            AVGTxRATE: { $avg: "$Tx Rate" },
            MaxRxRATE: { $max: "$Rx Rate" },
            MaxTxRATE: { $max: "$Tx Rate" }
        }
    },
    { 
        $project: { 
            _id: 0,
            DeviceName: 1, 
            ResourceName: 1, 
            Date: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$Date" } },
            AVGRxRATE: 1,
            AVGTxRATE: 1,
            MaxRxRATE: 1,
            MaxTxRATE: 1
        } 
    }
])
```

> Results in:

```
{
    "DeviceName" : "OLT",
    "ResourceName" : "OLT/Frame:0/Slot:19/Port:0",
    "Date" : "2016-11-07",
    "AVGRxRATE" : 522,
    "AVGTxRATE" : 176,
    "MaxRxRATE" : NumberLong(522),
    "MaxTxRATE" : NumberLong(176)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.Every 5 mn i get  a document and my goal is to make the aggregation by day(AVG,max) for each ressource name :
    DeviceName : "OLT"
    ResourceName : "OLT/Frame:0/Slot:19/Port:0"
    date : 2016-11-07
    AVG Tx Rate : NumberLong("176")
    AVG Rx Rate : NumberLong("522")
    MAX Tx Rate : NumberLong("176")
    MAX Rx Rate : NumberLong("522")
how ca i add the date and information like device name?

Comment: please, how can i add, the others information and change the day format?@dyouberg

Comment: Thanks @dyouberg for answering.I run the edit and grouping by ressource name but i have 1 document in the result.I add a new condition on "macth" in order to select all document but i stil have on result :     { "$match": {"CollectionTime": { $gte: ISODate("2016-11-05T00:00:00.000Z")},"Rx Rate": { $exists: true }}};How can ihave the average by date for all the document grouping by date and ressource name?

Comment: I try to move foward and i think i'm not so far anymore.thaks again for your help.I get only one date result with the request (see edit).I don't know how i can get the result by day.I have adjusted the match condition including all the required document.I don't know why you put $first.@dyouberg